# CssClass won't work

Tags: c#, css, class, button, dynamic

I'm building a table and dynamic placing out multiply buttons. The thing is that I'm also giving them a CSS class to use but it won't work and I have no idea to why?!

Here is the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowNum = 4;
    int cellNum = 10;
    int idcell = 1;
    int idrow = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++)
    {
        TableRow aNewRow = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < cellNum; j++)
        {
            TableCell aNewCell = new TableCell();
            Button aNewButton = new Button();

            aNewButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click_First_Row);
            aNewButton.ID = "R" + idrow + "B" + idcell;
            aNewButton.Text = "Boka";
            aNewButton.CssClass = "dynamicbuttons";

            aNewCell.Controls.Add(aNewButton);
            aNewRow.Cells.Add(aNewCell);
            idcell++;
        }
        Table1.Rows.Add(aNewRow);
        idrow++;
    }
}
```

and my CSS class

```
.dynamicbuttons {
    background-color:green;
    width:105px;
}
```

I have no idea why it won't work.

Comment: is the css class in the output html? do right click show hypertext in browser

Comment: No it's not. doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and I get the css class in the output html, so may be it´s something else in you environment that is cauing the problems.

My test markup:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .dynamicbuttons {
            background-color:green;
            width:105px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class TableForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowNum = 4;
        int cellNum = 10;
        int idcell = 1;
        int idrow = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++)
        {
            TableRow aNewRow = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < cellNum; j++)
            {
                TableCell aNewCell = new TableCell();
                Button aNewButton = new Button();

                //aNewButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click_First_Row);
                aNewButton.ID = "R" + idrow + "B" + idcell;
                aNewButton.Text = "Boka";
                aNewButton.CssClass = "dynamicbuttons";

                aNewCell.Controls.Add(aNewButton);
                aNewRow.Cells.Add(aNewCell);
                idcell++;
            }
            Table1.Rows.Add(aNewRow);
            idrow++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why it didn't work. I created a new CSS Sheet and just linked that into my CssClass, and it worked like a charm...